# What are recommended conventions for proper custom systemd service?

Tags: centos, systemd, selinux

I have a binary that does not have any built-in commands to restart or shutdown the process it creates. After looking at some built-in CentOS services I came to conclusion I cant use them as a template since a lot of them respect handy `SIGHUP` and such. Which means I'm gonna need to create .sh script to run and control it and here is where I have a few issues. The unit template has something called **PIDFile** but [I could not find any information in the  docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files#sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_File_Structure) if systemd manages and tracks the `PID` of the process it starts or it just a way to point out to `PID file` the service will create on their own. If it is the first then how would it track it properly if it is a script that will be executed via /bin/sh not the binary itself? Wouldn't it catch the `sh process`'s PID instead?

Looking at the HTTPD (Apache) service unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=The Apache HTTP Server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Documentation=man:httpd(8)
Documentation=man:apachectl(8)

[Service]
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/httpd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful
ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID}
```

How do they reference ${MAINPID} here if it is not declared anywhere?

My current assumption is that I have to pass to my .sh scripts argument that will handle start/stop/kill restart operations. Is this the commonly accepted practices? And how would that work with SElinux if I'm gonna run it as a limited user (which is a page I'm afraid to touch at all) - will the sh script be run as specified limited user too?

Comment: Did you see the [manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#PIDFile=) (Also see **Example 5. Traditional forking services** in there)

Comment: Thanks, that one explains it, so it just a pointer to the PID file that needs to be written by the process. If it is not implemented I have to implement it in the sh- script. I assume I would want to use `Type=forking` if I start the service via script? 
Also, that does not explain how `httpd` unit service manages to reference it out of nowhere?

Comment: You did see Example 5, right? "the $MAINPID variable will be available in ExecReload=, ExecStop=, etc." It's set by systemd. Depending on the type of service, it might set automatically or from PIDFile

Comment: Missed that, my bad. I'm correct in my assumption that if I use custom sh script to start/manage it then my `type` is `forking`?

Comment: Yes, since the command you're running is not the main process that systemd is managing. But I don't think you really need a script for all this. Why not run whatever command you'd use to kill the process in `ExecStop`?

Comment: I thought about it but then I wont be able to handle Reload since I need to kill it and then restart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My current assumption is that I have to pass to my .sh scripts argument that will handle start/stop/kill restart operations.

This is a common practice.  This is a common *bad* practice.  It's a Poor Man's Dæmon Supervisor, written badly in shell script (as they always are).  It's completely unnecessary.  In fact, pretty much everything that you are asking about is completely unnecessary.  Don't write wrapper shell scripts with Poor Man's Dæmon Supervisors and Bad Loggers.  Don't muck around with the rickety and dangerous PID file mechanism.  You are using a service manager, and *it does not need any of that*.

Make a `Type=simple` service unit.  You can `systemctl` it with `start`, `stop`, `restart`, `reload`, `enable`, and `disable` perfectly fine with *no silly wrapper scripting*.  A service manager like systemd and others *just remembers* the process ID, because it forked it in the first place.

If your program has some "dæmonization" mechanism, *turn it off* and *do not use it*.  Thanks to daemontools et al. where this has been a requirement for a long time, many programs have grown such mechanisms in the past more than 20 years, and others simply don't default to "dæmonizing" in the first place so can be used in their default operating modes.

Never use `Type=forking`.  It should be a last resort of desperation, as almost no programs *actually speak the protocol*.  Your program will undoubtedly not.  Choose `Type=simple` as standard.  Use early socket opening (configured with socket units), or `Type=notify`, if the program supports them.  Go back to the program's authors and encourage supporting early socket opening (the `LISTEN_FDS` protocol) if it does not, and it is a program that listens on sockets for connections.  Do not use any explicit `ExecStop` if a `TERM` signal stops your program, *which it should*.  Do not worry about `${MAINPID}`, which you won't have in your unit file in the first place.

And for goodness' sake don't look at Apache for an example of a simple and straightforward service for a novice to copy.  Apache thinks that `WINCH` should terminate processes.  Find something else to look at.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2001).  [*Mistakes to avoid when designing Unix dæmon programs*](http://jdebp.uk/FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html).   Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*You really don't need to daemonize. Really.*](http://jdebp.uk/FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/daemonize.html).  The systemd House of Horror.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*Readiness protocol problems with Unix dæmons*](http://jdebp.uk/FGA/unix-daemon-readiness-protocol-problems.html). Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: Thanks! Any chance you have any reading suggestions on how to make custom systemd service work in SElinux context with custom rules?